# I need MySQL code for the given question given below

Tags: mysql, sql

Write a query to display order_date, total order amount in each day. Give an alias name for total order amount as ‘TOTAL_SALE’. Sort the result based on order_date.

Comment: Hello @VivekaSekar , please show us what was your effort ? Also, it would be nice to see some data and expected result you wish to get from that data... What are the names of the tables and what are their join connections ?

Comment: Also, from what @VBoka had mentioned, MySQL questions should include some description of the tables you are working with (either a schema diagram or a `Create Table` script). Otherwise the closest answer one an provide is psuedo-code, and much less useful in a specific case like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Write a query to display order_date, total order amount in each day.*

```
SELECT order_date, 
       SUM(total_order_amount) 
FROM   mytable 
GROUP BY order_date;
```

*Give an alias name for total order amount as ‘TOTAL_SALE’*

```
SELECT order_date,  
       SUM(total_order_amount) AS 'TOTAL_SALE' -- your alias
FROM mytable 
GROUP BY order_date;
```

*Sort the result based on order_date*

```
SELECT order_date,  
       SUM(total_order_amount) AS 'TOTAL_SALE'
FROM mytable 
GROUP BY order_date
ORDER BY order_date ASC; --- your ordering
```

**Important Note:** Please change all respective field and table name according to your own field and table name. Unless your field and table name are exactly the same as the example query I wrote, the query won't work!